# Modifying hover in Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've noticed that :hover in Tailwindcss uses the defaults hover selector which causes 'stuck' hover states on mobile. Is there a way to modify the :hover function to do a @media(hover:hover) instead?

Comment: Touch-based devices do not have a hover state. I imagine that you are looking instead at the :focus or :active states. Tailwind allows you to apply classes to those pseudo selectors also, e.g. `focus:bg-blue-500`.

Comment: @SethWarburton that's the problem, mobile devices don't have a hover state, thus, a class like :hover will cause the effect to be stuck when a user presses on a button, etc. I'm trying to find a way for Tailwind to implement hover using the @media(hover:hover) instead of the regular :hover which causes said bug.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I believe the 'stuck' effect you are seeing is because you didn't set an appropriate state (i.e :focus) for touch-based devices. Try applying the styles you want using the correct selector.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

update: There is now a better way. See [this answer by Javier Gonzalez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323247/8130552)

original:
By far the simplest way is to add your own @media rule to the @*responsive*-class of rules in tailwind. How you can do that is described in the official tailwind documentation under the topic of [custom media queries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints/#custom-media-queries).

Simply add this to your config:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
          screens: {
            'hover-hover': {'raw': '(hover: hover)'},
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This translates to `@media (hover: hover) { ... }` in css. And voila, you could use `hover-hover:text-red` to display red text only for devices that have hover ability.

To make your own, leave 'raw' as is and change the other two attributes to whatever media query you want. The first attribute `hover-hover` is what you use in tailwind. The second `(hover: hover)` is what your actual css @media query looks like. E.g.: `hover: none` or `pointer: coarse`.

Now, go ahead and use hover-hover:hover:text-red to modify your hover states.

Comment: I found `raw: '(hover: hover)'` to be not enough and ended up using `raw: '(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine)'`

Comment: I found that this seems to take precedence over `active:` classes applied to the same element.

Answer (score 40):

Might be a bit late but the Tailwind team is already addressing this issue in Tailwind version 3 using a feature flag: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8394

<strike>Once a new version is published with these changes</strike> Starting on tailwindcss `v3.1.0`, you could include a feature flag in your configuration to look like:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just generate the hover variant using a plugin that, besides adding the :hover pseudo-selector, also wraps all of the rules inside an @media(hover:hover) rule:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

const hoverPlugin = plugin(function({ addVariant, e, postcss }) {
    addVariant('hover', ({ container, separator }) => {
        const hoverRule = postcss.atRule({ name: 'media', params: '(hover: hover)' });
        hoverRule.append(container.nodes);
        container.append(hoverRule);
        hoverRule.walkRules(rule => {
            rule.selector = `.${e(`hover${separator}${rule.selector.slice(1)}`)}:hover`
        });
    });
});

module.exports = {
  plugins: [ hoverPlugin ],
}
```

Comment: `(pointer: fine)` should be there too

Comment: `const hoverRule = postcss.atRule({ name: 'media', params: '(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine)' });` - this works

Comment: Thanks for this! The only issue I have found is when the selector contains dot character or arbitrary values. For instance:

hover:translate-x-0.5

The . part is incorrectly encoded. Do you know how to solve this? :)

Comment: @MichaelGallego period is not allowed in CSS identifier names. Escaping 0.5 as 0\2E5 should work, but I haven't tried and personally would just pick a naming scheme that is more aligned with valid CSS identifiers...

Answer (score 2):

[Using arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants)

```
<button 
    type="button"
    class="
        [@media(hover:hover)]:opacity-0
        [@media(hover:hover){&:hover}]:opacity-100
    ">
    <!-- ... -->
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The responsive attributes like `sm: md: lg:` will do those media query job for you. Refer example in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/). If you dont want to use hover state in mobile device. specify with eg:- `sm:hover:no-underline`

Comment: The problem with this approach is for large tablets on horizontal view, it is the same breakpoints as desktop, so if I need hover for desktop, the tablets will have stuck hover states if I use md or lg to target them. The @media( hover: hover ) seems to be the best way to target non-mouse devices for the moment I think.

Comment: By referring CSS-Tricks https://css-tricks.com/touch-devices-not-judged-size/ I think @media(hover: hover) is the solution.

Comment: Yup, @KPK that's why I'm wondering if Tailwind has a @media(hover:hover) instead of the regular :hover for its hover attribute.

Comment: I think we can create a RFC for this feature in GitHub

Comment: I tried doing `hidden sm:group-hover:inline` - does not work when hovering, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [create your own hover](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#generative-variants-for-custom-utilities) like below:

```
// styles.css

@variants hover {
  .banana {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Then use it like `class='hover:banana'`

Comment: it kinda makes your styling configuration distributed across different files which is not what you usually want

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you simply can override build-in variant with your own.

This way you still use the built-in `hover:` modifier in HTML that you are used to (without introducing a custom one like `hover-hover:`), but also you can add switching to `active:` when `hover:` is not available (`hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true` does't do it by its own)

Here is my solution:

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';
import plugin from 'tailwindcss/plugin';

export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('hover', [
        '@media (hover: hover) { &:hover }',
        '@media (hover: none) { &:active }',
      ]);
    }),
  ],
} satisfies Config;
```