# future: {hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true} is not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i'm working on a project using tailwind CSS and React. I'm trying to make sure that hover only works for devices that allow hover.

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
  }...
//Bunch of code
};
```

I'm using `"tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"`

Example:

```
      <div className="p-4 bg-red-600 hover:bg-blue-600">Hover Test</div>
```

[image]

I'm expecting "Hover Test" background to turn blue on mobile without hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe misunderstanding what `hoverOnlyWhenSupported` does. You can look at the PR this feature was introduced in https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8394

What it essentially does is when `hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true`, the hover features will only be applied when it is applicable, i.e., on Desktops, Laptops or anything with a pointer really.

So your expectation of

> I'm expecting "Hover Test" background to turn blue on mobile without hover

is wrong. If you want it to appear blue on mobile without hover, you have to do

```
<div className="p-4 bg-blue-600 md:bg-red-600 hover:bg-blue-600">Hover Test</div>
```

Breakdown:

1. `bg-blue-600`: As Tailwind is mobile first, this will apply to mobile-like resolutions, so you'll get blue background without hover as you wanted.
2. `md:bg-red-600`: This will apply to `md` screens and beyond. So for non-mobile like screens, you'll have red background and the hover style will be applied as long as the screens support it.

Comment: I've read through the documentation and I probably still don't understand. With regards to your second paragraph, what happens to the ```hover``` properties when ```hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true``` but when the device does not support hover? Do the properties you set just not show or what? And what's the difference between that and not having set "hoverOnlyWhenSupported:true"?

Comment: If you have `overOnlyWhenSupported: true` "Do the properties you set just not show or what?" Yes those hover properties won't be set at all so they won't show up.


`And what's the difference between that and not having set "hoverOnlyWhenSupported:true"`

Some browsers like Safari on mobile considered a tap/touch as hover and it was not expected behavior so people asked for an option where hover effect only applies where it should: desktops, macbooks, or anything with a mouse/trackpad, and that is why this option was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, If your use case is just

> **I'm expecting "Hover Test" background to turn blue on mobile without hover.**

You don't have to mess with `hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true`, just try this

```
<div className="p-4 bg-blue-600 md:bg-red-600 hover:bg-blue-600">Hover Test</div>
```

**What happens in the above code ?**

As tailwind-css follows `mobile-first` system. Any classes which are **not** trailed with breakpoint classes like `md:`, `sm:`, `lg:` and the like is applied to the mobile screen.

Therefore:

- For mobile screen: `bg-blue-600` is applied
- For `md:` screen and above:  `bg-red-600` is applied

**`hover:bg-blue-600`** is applied to both screens but if can see its affect only in the screen where you can hover using cursor, as you cannot potentionally hover using mobile phones you can't see it in effect.

Further adding to it a statment by @Seth Warburton

> Touch-based devices do not have a hover state. I imagine that you are looking instead at the `:focus` or `:active` states. Tailwind allows you to apply classes to those pseudo selectors also, e.g. focus:bg-red-600

---

**When do you use  `hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,`?**

This is brought up to address issue of:

[I've noticed that `:hover` in Tailwindcss uses the defaults hover selector which causes 'stuck' hover states on mobile.Is there a way to only apply hover styles when supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56755439/13431819)

Extending to [Amit Joki's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75872691/13431819) answer

> So now the hover features will only be applied when it is applicable, i.e., on Desktops, Laptops or anything with a pointer really.

Meaning only when there is cursor/pointer in your device such as Desktops, laptops and the like , hover works perfectly, otherwise `hover:` will not take effect and this is to overcome the stuck color change problem as mentioned above in the question link.